# find disk signature from wmi for a volume?

Tags: powershell, wmi

`gwmi win32_volume` provides me the details of the volume.

`gwmi win32_diskdrive` provides me the disk signature.

How do I obtain disk signature for a particular volume GUID using Powershell (volume GUIDs look like this `\\?\Volume{2e5e3ff7-fb5a-11e1-9924-80c16e6c465c}\`?

Using `Win32_LogicalDisk` is not an option for me, because some volumes may not be mounted, and they will not have a letter associated with them. Good example is `System Reserved` partition on Windows 7.

Comment: see http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/using-wmi-to-link-a-disk-volume-to-a-physical-disk-with-powershell/#comment-336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt find anything with gwmi for my requirement, so I am accessing diskpart from powershell.

In this case, I am fetching the disk signature which gwmi win32_diskdrive would have helped me obtain

```
$volumeCommand = "list volume" | diskpart
 $Pattern = 'XXXbbbXXXX'
 $Volume
for($i=5; $i -le $volumeCommand.length; $i++)
{
write-host $volumeCommand[$i]
 $matched = @(Select-String -inputobject $volumeCommand[$i] -Pattern $Pattern)
    if($matched ) {
   $Volume=$volumeCommand[$i -1 ]
     break
   }
}

$columnToGet = 1
$volumeName = $Volume | 
   %{ $_.Split(" ",[StringSplitOptions]"RemoveEmptyEntries")[$columnToGet] }

$selectCommand = "sel volume " +$volumeName  
$uniqueid = "uniqueid disk"
write-host $selectCommand
$volumeuniqueidCommand =  $selectCommand , $uniqueid  | diskpart
write-host $volumeuniqueidCommand


$signature = $volumeuniqueidCommand[$volumeuniqueidCommand.length-3].trimStart("Disk ID: ")
write-host $signature
$signature = [CONVERT]::toint32($signature,16)
write-host $signature
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best (and the only IMO) way is to use [`DiskExt.exe` from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896648.aspx)

You could use PowerShell to parse `DiskExt` output finding the diskdrive related the volume then use `win32_volume` to select his `signature` value

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this code:

```
$StrComputer = 'COMPUTER_NAME'
$DeviceId = "X:"
$wmiLogicalDiskQuery = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" + $DeviceId + "'} where AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
$PhysicaldiskPartitionName = (gwmi -Query $wmiLogicalDiskQuery).Name;
$wmiPhysicalDiskQuery = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + $PhysicaldiskPartitionName + "'} where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
$PhysicaldiskDriveName = (gwmi -Query $wmiPhysicalDiskQuery -Comp $StrComputer).DeviceID
$DiskSignature = (gwmi Win32_DiskDrive -Comp $StrComputer | where-object {$_.DeviceID -eq $PhysicaldiskDriveName} ).Signature
```

This is a slightly modified version from [here](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/262855-re-locate-physical-drive-signature-associated-logical-drive-na.html).

Comment: this associates win32.logicaldisk with win32.diskdrive and win32.diskpartition  there is win32.volume

Comment: [Isn't volume the same as logical disk?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disk)

Comment: By volume, i mean the win32_volume api here the device id is a volume guid eg : \\?\Volume{2e5e3ff7-fb5a-11e1-9924-80c16e6c465c}\              whereas win32_diskdrive uses something like //./PHYISICALDRIVE2...             A single diskdrive can have multiple volume associated

Comment: @NidaSahar: Thanks for the update. I edited your question. Please check and let me know if I understood you correctly.